# How to measure the CPU time in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

I need to measure the CPU time of a neighbor search algorithm. `timeit` is not suitable, because it is time-consuming.

I have tried `%%time`, but it only returns the wall time. Someone reported that `%%time` works on the Unix system. Is there any way to compute the CPU time under Windows system?

Comment: did you tried `%time`?

Comment: It still returns the wall time, but the value becomes 0 ns.

Comment: for me, it returned cpu time as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what system do you use? I use Win 10.